# In BASH, in specific directories, find sub-folders older than a X days

Tags: regex, bash, find

Using bash commands I would like to find all sub-folders in specific directories that are older than X days

This is my directory structure:

```
/usr/my_folder
```

Inside my_folder I have different sub-folders, like:

```
AAAA1
AAAA2
AAAA3
aaaa1
aaaa2
aaaa3
BBBB1
BBBB2
```

Each of these folders containes differents sub-folders, among with "MY_DATA". E.g.:

```
AAAA1/TEST
AAAA2/MY_DATA
BBBB1/TEST
BBBB2/MY_DATA
```

Starting from **my_folder**, I need to search all sub-folders of **AAA*** and **aaa*** that are older than for example 3 days. Additionaly, these sub-folders must be only in **MY_DATA** folder of **AAA*** and **aaa***.

I tried with this command, but it seems not to work

```
  find aaa* AAA* -type d -regextype sed -regex \".*/MY_DATA/*\" -mtime +3 -print0
```

Comment: What doesn't work ? Get an error ? Nothing ?

Comment: no results, no folders are displayed

Comment: "older than X days" meaning what, exactly? Lots of things will update a directory's mtime; does `stat AAA1/TEST` show the timestamp you expect?

Comment: Also, while `-print0` is the right thing for output being programatically read with `xargs -0` or `while IFS= read -r -d ''`, I'd suggest just using `-print` when testing.

Comment: I'd also avoid `-regex` here -- it's overkill. `-path '*/MY_DATA/*'` will do.

Comment: Why are you escaping the quotes in the regex ?

Comment: I thought it was the right method. Using */MY_DATA/* is working ok!!!

Comment: I'll add an answer that incorporates my comment, and also has a few other refinements.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Not if i beat you to it!

Comment: @123, well, we have different answers -- yours is to use `-regex` without the literal quotes, mine is to use `-path`. Both work. What I'm spending my time on right now, btw, is building a minimal reproducer; by including one in the answer, we can demonstrate how the question should have been ideally written.

Comment: @user3472065, in the future, when asking a question, consider trying to include a complete enough reproducer that someone else can copy-and-paste only what you provide and get the same output you're seeing. In this case, that means creating some directories, and setting (some of) their mtimes. See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve -- the "complete" and "verifiable" points, in particular.

Comment: @123, btw, if you're still inclined to post your own answer, I'd be happy to lend an upvote.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I thought your solution was better which is why i didn't post :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe the following reproducer (tested only against the GNU versions of `date` and `touch`):

```
# create a directory that should match, and two that should not
mkdir -p AAA1/MY_DATA/TARGET AAA1/MY_DATA/BAD AAA1/ALSO/BAD

# find an adequately conservative date for content that should match
target=$(date -d 'now - 5 days' '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')

# update the directory that should match to have that date as its mtime
# ...and also the one that should fail to match due to its name even if mtime is good
touch -d "$target" AAA1/MY_DATA/TARGET AAA1/ALSO/BAD

# Actually run the find command
find AAA* -type d -path '*/MY_DATA/*' -mtime +3 -print
```

This correctly emits only `AAA1/MY_DATA/TARGET` on its output.

Note that:

- `-path '*/MY_DATA/*'` is used rather than `-regex`, allowing glob-style patterns.
- Only syntactic quotes (directives to the shell), not literal quotes (data passed to `find`) are used (literal quotes, like `\"`, would become part of the pattern that filenames would be matched against).
- The reproducer uses `touch` to generate a directory with the correct date, allowing anyone to copy-and-paste the code above to test.